# Resultant of two like parallel forces and impact of two similar unlike parallel forces on the resultant

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

[image]

There are two like parallel forces P and Q acting at A and D respectively. Their resultant is acting at point E.  Now two more forces of equal magnitude and are unlike parallel have been made to act on point B and C respectively. Will the two force acting at B and C have any impact on te resultant P+Q like displacing it from Point E to some other point?

I know a torque is acting due to the two similar unlike forces but will it have any impact on the other two?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by impact?

Comment: I mean will the point of action of the resultant p+q be displaced because of the two similar unlike forces though their resultant is zero?

Answer (score 1):

Each force on an object acts separately.  You can combine their effect in pretty much any manner that you choose. However, the vector sum of all the forces acting on an object (or any system of masses) determines the acceleration of the center of mass, and the vector sum of all of the torques (about the center of mass) determines the angular acceleration of the object about the center of mass.

Comment: Will the resultant p+q displace from point E to any ither point due to the combined effect of two similar unlike parallel forces S?

Comment: The effective position for the resultant of two forces determines the torque that they might cause. That position is not effected by the action of other forces. However, the torque caused by four forces will be different from that caused by just two of them.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike forces or a '**couple**' always produce a torque when acted upon at equal distance from centre of mass if they have equal magnitude. 
Since the impact point is always considered to be at the centre of mass, there will be **no displacement** of point of impact by any forces whatsoever unless centre of mass shifts. 
 However here, since reference frame is not specified, only direction of forces matter rather than their location.